# Where are Windows XP default regional format values stored?

Tags: windows-xp, regional-settings

I am complained about wrong date time representation for a specific culture. I can fix that issue by changing values from control panel > language or manually editing the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International.

I want to fix the default values of the regional formats however I can't find where the settings are stored. Is it possible to be sure all the regional formats are correct?

Comment: Why are you still using XP? Microsoft is no longer supporting the OS, which makes your system very vulnerable.

Comment: Because our client vendor does not support Windows 7 or Windows 8 yet.

Comment: There .nls files in the System32 directory. They're referenced under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls`. You'll find more information at the [NLS Knowledge Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/dd565826). The [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163506.aspx) that describes creating a locale uses [Locale Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158), which is currently available just for Windows 8.